# How process hierarchy is maintained in Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

There are multiple ways of launching an exe from a process.

```
CreateProcess
ShellExecute
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

if you see in ProcessExplorer hierarchy is perfectly maintained.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

How does this parent-child relationship(among process) in Windows is handled ? 
Is there any way to set an exe to a different exe as a parent ?

Comment: It's a psuedo-heirarchy at best. When a process is launched Windows keeps track of which process ID launched it - that's all it is. It doesn't affect anything about either process - it's simply a bit of information the system remembers.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Potter. Is there any ways to change the parent for a process?

Comment: @raj: Since the parent process is not used for anything, there is no need to ever set it, less so reparent a process. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for Windows job objects. But as others say, you should explain why you are asking the question.

Comment: One thing about process hierarchy (other than just a bit of data Windows keeps), is that it directs the "kill process tree" operation for any program or script ([example](http://mackeblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/killing-subprocesses-on-windows-in.html)) that supports that operation such as Task Manager or Process Explorer.

Comment: Are you trying to start a process with a different parent than the one that starts it (there are some edge cases where this is desirable, and there is a documented method to do so) or are you trying to take an existing process and change its parent (which is both pointless and impossible)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get basic info about processes inheritance in Windows. Here is some useful link to start:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answering on your question: How to make some process parented to another - you just need to launch new process from "parent" process.